# Deepin & Windows dual boot - still booting only Windows

Tags: dual-boot, bios, deepin, boot-menu

I've recently installed Deepin by creating a partition on my SSD (50% each).

I already had Windows 10 installed, then I installed Deepin 20.3 from a bootable USB and it went without a problem. When the installation finished I had to restart it (as requested by Deepin).

The problem is that now I don't get any boot menu or anything like that - Windows automatically boots up without any way to change it.

I'm using an old Optiplex 3

Answer (score 0):

Hold down shift key while booting. The menu should appear. Then change '/etc/grub/defaults' to have menu timeout of 5. Run 'update-grub' or whichever program your distro uses to update grub. Let us know what happens.